# Can I Make this methods into a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

i have two methods to load nullable parameters into a SqlCommand;

```
    public static void LoadParameter<T>(Nullable<T> parameter, string name, SqlCommand cmd) where T : struct
    {
        if (parameter.HasValue)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, parameter);
        else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, DBNull.Value);
    }
```

and

```
    public static void LoadParameter(string parameter, string name, SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, parameter);
        else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, DBNull.Value);
    }
```

My questions are the next:
Can i make only one method to get the same result?
Can i add the "no Nullables" parameters to this (new) method and still working? I.E. Int16, Int32, Int64, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: You can just compare with null but then you won't compare for an empty string value. If you do, it gets messy really fast.

Comment: Do you need to set empty string to `DBNull.Value`? `string` is already null by default. I don't see why you couldn't just check `parameter == null`. You don't have to call `HasValue`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to replace empty string with DBNull?  Those have 2 different meanings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
public static void LoadParameter<T>(T parameter, string name, SqlCommand cmd)
{
    if (parameter != null && !string.Empty.Equals(parameter))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, parameter);
    else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, DBNull.Value);
}
```

The `string.Equals` will return `false` if compared with a non-`string`, so this code should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, but checking for null is not applicable on value types, for instance int32 will default to 0. How would you find whether 0 is the real value or a null representation. If you have specific case for each value type then you could something like this

`public void LoadParameter<T>(T parameter, string name, SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            switch (typeof(T).Name)
            { 
                //TODO: case statements to handle different types.
            }
        }`

Comment: You could use `default(T)` instead of comparing `0`.

Comment: All my no nullables parameters are obligatory and i have business rules to validate them, in this case, if the value is 0, then 0 is a valid value